# How to generate .pdf files with vim-latex suite?

Tags: dvips, ps2pdf, vim-latex

I'm having trouble setting up vim-latex suite to produce .pdf files.  Right now the `\ll` (`<leader>ll`) command will compile latex.  Then `\lv` (`<leader>lv`) will produce a .dvi file.

Is there another command to initiate the standard .tex -> .dvi -> .ps -> .pdf build sequence?

Alternatively, can I configure `\lb` to create .ps and .pdf files?

So far I have tried the following commands from the vim-latx [documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite.html):

```
let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi = 'latex --interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_ps = 'dvips -Ppdf -o $*.ps $*.dvi'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'ps2pdf $*.ps'
```

However, this doesn't build ps or pdf file.  I can still make them manually with `dvips mydoc.dvi` and `ps2pdf mydoc.ps`.

Comment: Do you want to compile through the tex > dvi > ps > pdf or would compiling directly with pdflatex be of interest?  Only thing that comes to mind right now is are you opening tex files as latex or plaintex?  Does adding `let g:tex_flavor='latex'` make a difference

Comment: I slightly prefer tex > dvi >ps >pdf, but pdflatex is ok too.  How can I check for latex vs plaintex?  `let g:tex_flavor='latex'` and `let g:tex_flavor='latex'` don't have any effect; either way, only the .dvi file is generated.

Comment: I find vim-latex-suite just too complicated.  All you need to produce a pdf is to type `:!pdflatex %`, and then when you've done that once, `:!<up-arrow>` will let you do it again...

Comment: Thanks @Thruston.  I took your advice and removed vim-latex.  I added `map <Leader>ll :!pdflatex %:p` to my vimrc.  Now `\ll` builds the latex file.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that you had `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` set to its default value of `dvi` (at least for Windows/Unix according to [the documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-compiling.html#Tex_DefaultTargetFormat)).

With `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` set to `dvi`, compilation will follow the chain set by `g:Tex_FormatDependency_dvi` rather than `g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf` which by default will only lead to `g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi` being executed.

In order to get the `dvi -> ps -> pdf` chain working, you would need

- `let g:Tex_FormatDependency_dvi = 'dvi,ps,pdf'` rather than `let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'` so that when Vim-LaTeX tries to build a `dvi` file (as it defaults to), it follows the `dvi -> ps -> pdf` chain.

or

- `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'` rather than `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='dvi'` so it follows the `g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf` which you defined in the question to perform the `dvi -> ps -> pdf` chain.

For running `pdflatex` you should be able to just use `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'` with `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf` and `g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf` left to their defaults.

Answer (score 1):

If your latex project contains multiple source files, then set `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'` doesn't help. In this case, you need to set `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf'` then the pdf file will be generated when you type `\ll`. So, just add

- `let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats = 'pdf'`
- `let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'`
  to your `~/.vimrc` file, the problem should be solved.

Comment: This description of the use of `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` doesn't seem to agree with my reading of the documentation (http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/compiling-multiple.html).

Comment: Hi, @DaiBowen . I read the documentation. It does seem that I misunderstood the meaning of `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats`. But I did a little experiment with it. It seems that only when I set both the `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` and `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` to pdf my latex-suite generates a pdf file. Lacking either of these two variables fails. And I have a latex project with multiple files.

Comment: `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` is indeed important to getting the right compilation route, but `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` shouldn't prohibit compilation (but if it doesn't include whatever `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat` is set to then `\ll` will only trigger a single run of (pdf)latex rather than repeated).  Imo if you can reproducibly not compile with `g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats` set to empty there's a bug to be reported, I'd hazard that it's unlikely though.